# Variable lengths differ error message in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression on the spam dataset from `https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/`.  The dependent variable is in the last column, which is given as V58 after I import the data in R studio.  But I get the error message "variable lengths differ (found in 'V1')"

I've checked for na's using na.omit, I tried removing the V1 column just to see if that fixes the issue, but I get the same message.  I tried using the old cv.glm function instead, but that does not work.  I also tried referring to the dependent variable as spam.data$V58.  I am stuck.  What am I missing?  Below is the code I have so far to just get the model.

```
spam.data <- data_frame(read.table(datapathname))

dim(spam.data)
str(spam.data)
summary(spam.data)

set.seed(2718)
row.number = sample(1:nrow(spam.data), 0.7*nrow(spam.data))
train = spam.data[row.number,]
test = spam.data[-row.number,]
dim(train)
dim(test)

model.logistic = glm(as.factor(spam.data[58])~., data=train, family=binomial) #The error gets thrown here.

summary(model.logistic)
```

I should also say that the way I created the data set was to copy and paste the data from the website to a text file and read it into R from that file.  The info on the site says we should get 4601 rows and 58 columns, and indeed we get this size dataset.

Any ideas?